# Containers and Caching

Tags: docker, containers

Suppose we have two containers created consecutively from the same image on the same VM and they are running the same command. More info here the input files are huge and I'm mounting a volume.

Now, is it possible that the second container takes advantage of memory caching (We are not talking about image caching). If so, how can I deactivate that?

I can see a difference in terms of execution time b/w two runs for these containers running in a consecutive way vs. when I reboot the VM in b/w. Thanks!

Comment: If two containers share the same memory blocks then it defeats the use of containers, no? Anyway you may want to use separate memory caching layer, like putting your data in Redis or anything so they can be shared.

Comment: The Linux kernel caches a lot of things to improve performance; if the two containers are using the same file (especially from a bind-mounted volume or from the same image), and nobody's writing to it, they probably do share a cache inside the (shared) kernel.  Why do you want to disable that?